# Why can't I start the top command in batch mode, stop it, and then resume it with fg?

Tags: linux, bash, signals, tty

I don't know why, so I would like to ask Gen...

`$ top -b`

and then Ctrl + Z to stop it, and then bring it back to foreground with

`$ fg %1`

It does not work as desired.
The screen seems to be broken (see the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TziTZ.png) ), and above all, it will not accept input such as Ctrl + C.

Comment: Why are you using `-b` (batch mode) ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's a small bug in `top`.

See source code [top.c](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/-/blob/4939a1da8dcd518c37a0505fba97105af8ed3798/top/top.c):

```c
 645         /*
 646          * Catches:
 647          *    SIGTSTP, SIGTTIN and SIGTTOU */
 648 static void sig_paused (int dont_care_sig) {
 661    fflush(stdout);
 662    raise(SIGSTOP);
 663    // later, after SIGCONT...
 664    if (-1 == tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSAFLUSH, &Tty_raw))
 665       error_exit(fmtmk(N_fmt(FAIL_tty_set_fmt), strerror(errno)));
 666 #ifndef RMAN_IGNORED
 667    putp(Cap_rmam);
 668 #endif
 669    if (keypad_xmit) putp(keypad_xmit);
 670    putp(Cursor_state);
 671    Frames_signal = BREAK_sig;
 672    (void)dont_care_sig;
 673 } // end: sig_paused
 ...
3798    // lastly, establish a robust signals environment
3799    memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));
3800    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
3801    //with user position preserved through SIGWINCH,we must avoid SA_RESTART
3802    sa.sa_flags = 0;
3803    for (i = SIGRTMAX; i; i--) {
3804       switch (i) {
....
3810          case SIGTSTP: case SIGTTIN: case SIGTTOU:
3811             sa.sa_handler = sig_paused;
3812             break;
....
3823       }
3824       sigaction(i, &sa, NULL);
3825    }
```

This is what happens:

1. In line 3810, `top` explicitly registers its SIGTSTP handler `sig_paused()`.
2. When CTRL-Z is pressed, it sends SIGTSTP to `top -b`.
3. When `top` receives SIGTSTP, in `sig_paused()` it stops itself by sending SIGSTOP (line 662).
4. `fg` sends SIGCONT to `top` and wakes it up.
5. In line 664 when `top` is waken up, it puts the tty in *raw* mode <sup>(it should not do this when `-b` is specified)</sup>.
6. When the tty is in *raw* mode, keys like CTRL-C will not generate SIGINT so CTRL-C cannot kill it.

Comment: Whoa!
How gracious of you to respond!
I was convinced. I will try to read the source code too.
Thank you!